# How to re-merge an already merged branch?

Tags: git, merge

I have a commit graph that looks something like the one below. Commits marked with `*` represent lots of commits.

```
   A*
   |
   B---------
   |        |
   C*       D*    <- old feature branch
   |        |
   E---------
   |
   F*
   |
   G      <- master
```

The merge commit E was done incorrectly and some changes (not all) in C*  have been lost. How can I redo that merge to reintroduce the changes into the current master?

Everything has already been pushed (open source project), so changing history is not an option.

I tried creating a patch from the commits C* and apply that to the master, but because *some* of the changes from C* have been merged correctly and because the project evolved since that commit, about 80% of the patch fails.

Ideally, we would take all the changes in C*, apply them to master and resolve all conflicts. But because the branches have already been merged, git doesn't detect any changes and won't allow to merge again.

```
$ git checkout 5bc5295   # C
HEAD is now at 5bc5295... cleanup

$ git checkout -b "missing-commits"
Switched to a new branch 'missing-commits'

$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.

$ git merge missing-commits
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Did you try git revert the incorrect commits. This will undo the change introduced by bad commit and changes that were lost. Something like git revert E.

Comment: @Eyorther how would that help, as the merge is the faulty commit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Ideally, we would take all the changes in C*, apply them to master and resolve all conflicts.

No, ideally you would rewind time, do the merge as it was back then (but correctly, this time), then reapply the `F*` changes and end up with a correct `master`.

You can do it like this:

```
git checkout missing-commits
git checkout -b correct-merge
git merge D    # do it right, this time around!
git checkout master
git checkout -b correct-master
git rebase --onto correct-merge wrong-merge correct-master # have fun with the mother of all rebases!
```

If you manage to handle all the conflicts during the rebase, you will end up with exactly what you wanted, originally, in the branch `correct-master`.

Since you do not want to change history, you could then create a big patch and apply that to your current `master`, but I like this approach more (assuming you did all your work in your working directory `yourrepos`):

```
cd yourrepos ; git checkout correct-master ; cd ..
cp -a yourrepos newrepos
rm -rf newrepos/.git
cd yourrepos ; git checkout master ; cd ..
cp -a yourrepos/.git newrepos/
```

Now, when you enter `newrepos` and do a `git status`, you will be on branch `master` and will see precisely all changes between `master` and `correct-master`, as if you had applied a patch. It will catch deleted files, new files, changed files, changed permissions, changed symlinks and so on.

Ideally, if everything went right, it will show exactly the missing commits from `C`. Use your favourite variant of `git add` and finally a nice `git commit` (or several, if you prefer), and you're done. No history has been rewritten.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the need for the rebase command. Once I have the correct-merge branch, couldn't I just merge that into master? How would that be different from using rebase?

Comment: @JohnM, it could work or could not work, but it is semantically not the right thing to do. The merge operation is made to bring two things together that branched off of a common ancestor. This is not really what you are doing here. Rebase, instead is made to graft a series commit at another place on the tree, which is exactly what we are doing here. The practical benefit is that rebase does so commit-by-commit, so it is likely to get easier conflict resolution, albeit if you are unlucky, and the same conflict occurs on almost any commit, it can get abysmal. You can try both of course!

Comment: Thanks, I was able to rebase it. One small change that I had to do was to rebase starting after the wrong merge, and not the missing commits: `git rebase --onto correct-merge wrong-merge correct-master`. But I finally understand how this works and it's pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @JohnM, I have edited your rebase into the answer. Glad it worked out mostly! ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can try by a cherry-pick:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick B..[last_commit_of_C*]
```

Git may ask you to confirm the cherry-pick since the commits are in the ancestors.

Answer (score 3):

Git stores snapshots and detects changes on the fly, so the way to work with the difference between a bad commit and a good one is to record the good as  a descendant the bad—pretty much the same as anything, come to think of it.  Use `git reset --soft` to tell git the correct ancestry:

```
git checkout badmerge^1    # generate the right result 
git merge badmerge^2

... Fix conflicts ...
git commit

git reset --soft badmerge  # as an improvement on the wrong result
git commit

git checkout master        # merge the difference now that git sees it
git merge HEAD@{1} -m "applying corrections to a bad merge"
```

Comment: Can you clarify why we should use `git reset --soft` to alter the ancestry? I guess it ensures your merge takes priority, so you don't have to solve conflicts between your merge and the bad merge?

Comment: @RobinGreen the soft reset's only effect is to re-hang the checkout label, the commit that will be used as your next commit's parent.  So you rerun the merge and do it right this time, and when you commit those results with the wrong results as their parent, merging _those_ differences (one would hope properly, heh), you get what you're after.  The bad merge is the new merge _base_, all changes are calculated from that so nothing from its prior history can show up as a conflict.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get "fatal: Cannot do a soft reset in the middle of a merge."

Comment: @RobinGreen you have to do it after committing the merge, that commit is a throwaway but it's down around 100 bytes in the repo that'll eventually get discarded.

Comment: OK, got it. Unfortunately, I still had to solve conflicts in the final merge. I think `-s ours` would avoid that. But that could be risky if there were further changes to the conflicted area after the bad merge - e.g. a failed attempt to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of creating plain patches and applying them to use `git format-patch` and `git am`. This should give you the normal conflict state situation where you then can use a merge tool too resolve the conflicts, unlike with `git apply` where the application just fails.

Comment: You can `git apply -3` a patch produced by `git format-patch` or `git show`, to invoke the merge machinery. (`git am` uses `git apply -3` internally.)